# PHPStorm out of memory + no JVM installation found

Tags: yii2, phpstorm

PHPStorm после установки yii-2 стал зависать – вылезает сообщение об увеличении XMS. Это при запуске index.php файла фреймворка yii-2, нового - начинаю только знакомится с ним.

1. Ставлю вместо 512mb – 2048mb, shotdown. При последующем запуске снова стоит 512mb и виснет.
2. Залез в about - запущена 32 битная версия IDE, попробовать решил запустить 64 битную - на скрине ошибка об отсутствии JAVA.
3. Скачал JAVA и прописал переменную в средах как для system так и для user.
   Путь без скобок, к основной папке. Не помогает.
4. В терминале версия отражается корректно при установке пути в папку bin (смотри скрин - красный текст).

Если с установленной JAVA запустить 32-битную IDE - виснет. 64-битная IDE не запускается и по сей день. Google говорит - надо запустить и виснуть IDE перестанет.

**Вынужден просить вас о помощи в решении проблемы. Как мне запустить 64-битную версию PSPStorm, если он ее не видит? В какие файлы лезть и что править?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сколько оперативки свободной, когда шторм не запущен? Может все таки обновить его? 2015 год это очень старая версия, там много чего исправлено уже. В том числе и утечки всякие по памяти.

Comment: fedornabilkin, свободно 12.7gb, при запуске IDE становится свободным 11.8gb. Я попробую обновиться, но проблема с JAVA все равно останется ведь. Не факт что и новая версия не выдаст такой ошибки, или это может быть багом IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалил IDE 9.0 версию 2015 года, установил 2018 года - 2018.1.4v, теперь не запускается 32-битная версия IDE, но 64-битная работает. В окне about все ОК, 64-битная отображается, конфликтов при запуске нет.

Вот такое вот получилось решение. Если кто понял логику решения проблемы - буду очень рад прочесть, чтобы вникнуть в суть проблемы.

Comment: Рекомендую перед обновлением сделать экспорт настроек и конфигураций. Сегодня на работе коллега обновился до последней версии и слетели все коннекты. Так и не смог найти.